# Sendgrid Integration requirement

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I am just trying out the SendGrid service to send emails from my Test-WebApi. For this install the Sendgrid Nuget Package. Now I go to do sign-up to sendgrid website there I am filling my details on profile section then there is a option for Website and it is mandatory field so questions are :

Why this filled is required ?

I have entered a testwebsite url then will it make me trouble for sending mails from my web api?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the registration process for a tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason SendGrid asks for this, is that we manually review every account that we allow to send email through our API. One of the factors we check is the website. ***You may send email through SendGrid without a website***, however, we will likely ask you a number of questions over email after you signup. Just answer these and you should be good to go.

Once we give you access to the API nothing in your "Profile Information" will affect the use of the API. You will be able to send email from any domain you so choose.

Comment: Thanks Nick, One more thing i have just sign-up with the SendGrid and it saying that "Your account is still being provisioned. You will not be able to send out any email." so how much time this thing will take. because i wanted to check this service asap.

Comment: We aim for provisioning to take no longer than an hour. So look for a provisioning email to hit your inbox in the next little bit. Just respond to it with answers to any questions we ask in it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick, Just waiting for an email :)